# Aggregating ratios in Crystal Reports pivot table

Tags: crystal-reports, aggregate, pivot-table, crosstab

Simple pivot table:
[image]

In this case, I'm pulling back 5 fields from the database:

1. Category
2. Year
3. Quarter
4. Numerator
5. Divisor

2 unfortunate facts. First, the year/quarters drift to provide a rolling 8-quarter view.  Consequently, there will usually be 1 full year and 2 partials with their respective quarters.  Second, the measures to be displayed are ratios of numerator to divisor.  Naturally, Crystal is assuming that I want to divide everything and *then* total it, which is not correct.

How do you get the pivot table totals to calculate correctly as SUM({Numerator})/SUM({Denominator})? Since there are multiple levels in play, the Sum({Numerator}, {Attribute})/Sum({Denominator}, {Attribute}) doesn't seem to work or I'm missing an extra element to it.

This crosstab is intended to replace a report that individually calculated every cell, and is not viable for long-term maintenance.  If the totals can't be corrected, we'll have to revert back to that format.

Comment: in the image displayed what is your calculation? which fields are you trying to manipulate

Comment: The image was a mockup for reference.  The shaded areas would be the problem areas.  At the individual category/year/quarter intersections (white areas), the formula {Numerator}/{Denominator}*100 accurately yields the percentage conversion we're after.  The totals, however, aggregate these resulting percentages instead of aggregating the two metrics and then applying division.

Comment: you can try embeeded summary and write your formula there.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I'm not sure how one would go about injecting columns into the pivot table to get the subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create a cross tab... you can insert saperate column or row inside the existing column using the option `embeeded summary`

```
Right click---> Embeeded Summary ---> insert embeeded summary
```

This will insert a row as `Edit This Formula`.

Now on the newly created cell

```
Right click---> Embeeded Summary ---> Edit Calculation formula
```

This will open a window there write your division formula.